# How can I set default setFrom in Zend_Mail

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, zend-mail

How can I set the default setFrom field with title in Zend_Mail

If I send mail like this

```
public function sendActivationEmail($id) {
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail   ->addTo('emailId1@gmail.com',"Recepient Name")
            ->setFrom("emailId1@gmail.com","Site Name")
            ->setSubject("My Subject")
            ->setBodyText("Some body msg")
            ->setBodyHtml("Some body msg")
            ->send();
}
```

I get an email in nice format with From Field in mail as "Site Name"

But If I send mail without setFrom, I still get the mail, but the title is "emailId1@gmail.com". I dont want to use SetFrom() just to get "Site From". Is there a way I can set it so that "Site Name" gets picked up by default ?

I have followed this  tutorial for setting up my email : http://www.zendcasts.com/introduction-to-zend_mail/2010/02/

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a default email address for the from attribute, you can use [`setDefaultFrom()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.multiple-emails.html) static method like this:

For example, in your boostrap:

```
protected function _initFromMail(){
    // You can get the mail from an init file
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultFrom('emailId1@gmail.com', 'Site Name');
}
```

In your function, the from adress mail is automatically fiiled.

```
public function sendActivationEmail($id) {
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail   ->addTo('emailId1@gmail.com',"Recepient Name")
            ->setSubject("My Subject")
            ->setBodyText("Some body msg")
            ->setBodyHtml("Some body msg")
            ->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just create a subclass of `Zend_Mail` and use that. Something like the following:

```
class My_Mail extends Zend_Mail
{
    public function __construct($charset = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($charset);
        setFrom('emailId1@gmail.com, 'Site Name');
    }
}
```

Then usage would be:

```
$mail = new My_Mail();
$mail   ->addTo('emailId1@gmail.com','Recipient Name')
        ->setSubject('My Subject')
        ->setBodyText('Some body msg')
        ->setBodyHtml('Some body msg')
        ->send();
```

The usual requirements about how to autoload classes in the `My_` pseudo-namespace would apply. For example, you could add:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = My_
```

to your `application/config/application.ini`